# In VS Code Can I Validate my Javascript But Ignore a Specific Typescript Error?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am writing Javascript in Visual Studio Code (not Typescript).  However, I added `"checkJs": true` ("Enable type checking on JavaScript files") to my `compilerOptions` in `jsconfig.json` to enable automatic imports.

Now that I have done that, I'm getting *Typescript* errors (squiggly lines), for instance:

> JSX element type 'Foo' does not have any construct or call signatures.  ts(2604)

I could remove these by disabling validity checking, but then I'd lose normal Javascript validity checking.

My question is: is it possible to have automatic imports, and *Javascript* validity checking, but not have *Typescript* errors in VS Code?  For instance, is there some flag I can set in `jsconfig.json` to disable errors with "ts" at the end?

And if not, how do I fix Typescript errors in a Javascript file ... without having to adopt Typescript?

**EDIT:** Just to help clarify the *kind of* solution I'm imagining ... let's say we were talking about ESLint here.  Yes I could add a comment at the top of a file to make ESLint ignore that file, but then I lose all linting whatsoever.

I'm more looking for the equivalent of being able to say `"ts2604": false` or `"ts*": false` in an `.eslintrc` file, or something more like that.  In other words, I don't want to adopt Typescript, or lose all type awareness either ... I just want VS Code's great *Javascript* features, without large chunks of my code being underlined by error/warning messages that I can't do anything about.

Comment: I've only ever had a `jsconfig.js`: I've never had a `tsconfig.json`, because I've never done Typescript.  The only way TypeScript is related is that using it in some sense, via the `checkJs` compiler option, is somehow necessary to get automatic imports.  But just because I want VS Code to use Typescript to infer some types when importing, that doesn't mean I care about some code lacking a type *in my Javascript code* ... which is why I'm looking for some sort of compromise.

Comment: I copied my `jsconfig.js` (including `checkJs: true`) into a `tsconfig.js`: it did nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately that just describes the various ways of enabling type-checking, such as the `checkJs` option in `jsconfig.js` I'm using.  However that mechanism , and the others listed (eg. `// @ts-check`) seem to be an all or nothing deal: you get all the features and the TS warnings, or none.  I'm trying to get the features, but somehow disable/hide/ignore the Typescript warnings about not having types for things in my JS files (because my jS files have no type definitions). Even just a way to "turn off" certain warnings/errors by code (eg. don't show me `ts(2604)` errors) would be helpful.

Comment: But it's not in any way about Typescript, except to the degree that VS Code involves it: my question is 100% about writing *Javascript* in Visual Studio Code, so I feel like Typescript tags would be misleading.

Comment: Does // @ts-nocheck on top of js file work?

Comment: Doing that disables all checking whatsoever: I not only lose automatic imports, I also lose even basic stuff like squiggly lines under undefined variables.  But since my goal is to get all that stuff ... and just not Typescript errors (or specifically not  Typescript errors about undefined types, since I have no way of defining types in Javascript) ... `// @ts-nocheck` doesn't help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS Code's JavaScript type checking is powered by TypeScript. The errors you are seeing in your JS files are not TypeScript language errors, they are the TypeScript engine saying: "Hey this JavaScript code looks like it is invalid". The TypeScript engine tries to understand JavaScript as well as possible, but JavaScript's dynamic nature can sometimes trip it up and you may need to help it along with some JSDoc annotations .

So ideally you should address these errors. If this is not possible, you can suppress the errors using a `// @ts-ignore` comment on the line above the error (this is offered as a quick fix for the error)

[This TypeScript feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38409) also tracks the ability to suppress specific error codes.

Comment: Thank you. "you may need to help it along with some JSDoc annotations" - Could you point me to any sort of resource on how I'd do that?  I've heard that in theory you can "do Typescript through JSDoc", and that would let me specify types without using Typescript, but I'm not familiar with how to actually accomplish that.  Also, that GitHub issue seemed promising ... but it seemed (so far at least) to lack traction.

Answer (score 4):

This could be a red herring, but are all your errors JSX related? TypeScript can handle JSX (in `*.tsx` ot `*.jsx` files) if you specify the factory to use for the JSX. The error looks like TS can't find the factory class (so it's got `<Foo>` and doesn't know what to pass it to). Typically this will be something like (the settings say React, but they're the same for Preact or other JSX libraries):

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "jsxFactory": "probably the same as transform-react-jsx setting in your plugins"
}
```

There's much more on that [in the TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html).

Generally I find it best practice to fix TS errors before JS anyway, but that isn't always practical, so another option is adding `// @ts-ignore` on the preceding line or `// @ts-nocheck` to skip type checking in the file.

`// @ts-ignore` is really intended for this kind of situation, but it's not a long term fix - you're upgrading, you know it works, you just need TS to skip the failing check for now. But, when you *know* the code works and TS is missing a definition somewhere it can be the right patch.

Comment: Thank you. I am using JSX, but I don't get errors on most of my JSX.  In that specific instance, a component was being brought in via a hook (instead of via `import`) and that caused Typescript to not be able to infer a type.  I tried to add a `"jsxFactory"` property (I already had a `"jsx": "react"` one), but VS Code told me it was invalid.  Also, I wasn't clear on what to set it to, as I don't have a `transform-react-jsx` setting (an old Babel config file I used to use has it; was this a Babel setting that got removed perhaps?)

Comment: @machineghost Oh, in that case you can still tell TS where to find `Foo()` with `/// <reference path="path_to_your_defs/foo.d.ts" />` at the top of the file.

Comment: I see ... but aren't I adopting Typescript at that point?  My goal was to stick to JS.

Comment: @machineghost TypeScript just adds type checking to JS. You don't have to switch to TS, but if you want to check types you need to tell TS what the types look like, even in your JS. It needs to know what `Foo` looks like (or you can `declare Foo: any` and it won't care). You can use `// @ts-nocheck` to skip one problem file or `// @ts-ignore` to skip one line.

Comment: I emphasize, you have to add `// @ts-ignore` on the line BEFORE the line to be ignored, adding to end of the line does NOT work :D

Answer (score 1):

Lately I have been coding in React with Visual Studio Code and we have a team recommandation for using [ESLint extension](https://eslint.org/).

It has many configuration capabilities, and the following one may match with your needs :

> eslint.probe = an array for language identifiers for which the ESLint extension should be activated and should try to validate the file. If validation fails for probed languages the extension says silent. Defaults to ["javascript", "javascriptreact", "typescript", "typescriptreact", "html", "vue"].

Comment: Thank you. I am using that extension, but if I understand the `eslint.probe` setting, it's essentially just another "turn off all validation" (by file extension) ... similar to adding `//@ts-ignore` to every file.  I don't want that; I *want* validation features ... I just want to be able to turn off the ones that I can't address.